# Lumen API returns 422 error when passing body as JSON

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, lumen, create-react-app

I'm trying to post from react application to php backend (Lumen 5.3) via `fetch` api.

My POST is as follows:

```
function login(userData, onError, cb) {
  return fetch('/v1/auth/login', {
    method: 'post',
    body: JSON.stringify(userData),
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  }).then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(cb)
    .catch(onError);
}
```

where `userData` is:

```
const userData = {
  email: this.state.fields.username,
  password: this.state.fields.password,
};
```

However I am receiving an error:

[image: 422 error]

Which would indicate that my body is incorrect?  I suspect this because when I test an equivalent request in postman and do not pass `password` in the body I will receive a 422 error:

[image: 422 error in postman]

This leads me to believe that the body is maybe not formatted correctly?

One part that is sort of suspicious is that if I log my response from the php backend there is no body returned.  In theory if my body is formatted incorrectly I should receive the following from the backend:

```
{
    "email": [
        "The email field is required."
    ],
    "password": [
        "The password field is required."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my Lumen API does not accept JSON as the body.

The fix for now is to modify my request as follows:

```
function login(userData, onError, cb) {
  return fetch('/v1/auth/login', {
    method: 'post',
    body: serialize(userData), // no longer passing json
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' // no longer passing json
    },
  }).then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(cb)
    .catch(onError);
}

function serialize(obj) {
  let str = [];
  for(let p in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    }
  return str.join("&");
}
```

Where `userData` is:

```
const userData = {
  email: this.state.fields.username,
  password: this.state.fields.password,
};
```

And now everyone is happy :)  Hope this helps!